# Web app in angular uploaded to go daddy shows empty page

Tags: angular

Hi i uploaded the dist folder to godaddy in the public_html folder, no errors but i just shows a blank page.

I have tried with the hashlocationstrategy but still nothing.

Thanks for your help in advance. :)

Comment: Have you uploaded dist folder also or only file which are inside dist folder?

Comment: Can you look at Chrome developer tools, click on the network tab and see some errors? Look at the console for errors?

Comment: make sure you are pointing inside dist folder and may i know what error you are getting check from developer  tools network tab

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for your answers in the end i only had to upload the files by themselves without the folder dist and it worked!!

Just uploaded every file directly into the public_html folder, and created the assets images folder and uploaded the images there.

Thank you so much for your help, and have a nice week :)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by changing the folder location  in the "index.html"  to the folder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).